# If $y''+y'=x+y$ what will be $y''+4y'=?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $$y''+y'=x+y$$ what will be   $$y''+4y'=?$$

Comment: Are you sure you copied the question correctly?

Comment: yes..................

Comment: What sort of answer are you hoping for?  It clearly equals $x+y+3y'$ if that is of any use.

Comment: Assuming you have copied it correctly, have you tried solving the ODE given?

Comment: @almagest can I get the answer without solving the D.E?

Comment: Apparently you haven't managed to so. It doesn't look that hard to solve, so why not solve it? Life is too short to get the best, shortest solution every time. It is better to learn to get any correct solution as quickly as you can.

Comment: The answer depends on data not in evidence. Is the task description complete?

Answer (score 0):

As @almagest said, just solve the differential equation, it's not that hard.

I'll give only an outline here.

This is a linear second order differential equation with constant coefficients.

The characteristic quadratic is $D^2 + D - 1 = 0$, which has two real, distinct roots. You should be able to get the general solution from this easily.

The particular solution is clearly a polynomial, and you only need to consider a general cubic function since any higher degree functions will leave degree two or higher terms after differentiating. So consider $y =ax^3 + bx^2 +cx +d$ and substitute that into the differential equation. You'll quickly find the leading two coefficients vanish, leading to a simple linear function. So the solution (in the form $y=f(x)$) is the sum of the general and particular solutions.

The rest is just basic differentiation and simplification to present the final answer in the nicest form possible.